# How can I add status indicators to a section in GitHub?

Tags: github, text-formatting, status

I'm reading [Basic writing and formatting syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#headings) of GitHub but failed to link directly to section in ordered file like this:

[image: GitHub example]
What is the syntax to do like this?:

[image: Link requirement]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Status indicators such as [image: repo badges] are often referred to as [Code Repository Badges](https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges).  These repo badges can be applied with Markdown to show on your wiki or documentation page; many dynamic status badges including the `Build | Passing` badge may be dependent on integrations with other services.

[Github.com/dwyl/repo-badges project](https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges) has a good list of the most commonly used badges; you can also create your own at http://shields.io, which also has a good list of devops-related and popularity/rating badges.